# Polymer Web Components Documentation

Tags: web, polymer, code-documentation

Where can I find the documentation for web components managed by PolymerElements? I'm here: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dialog, and the page says to see the Docs, but doesn't provide a link. I just want to know what kind of api the paper-dialog has.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find the documentation for web components managed by PolymerElements?

The docs are all hosted at https://www.webcomponents.org.

> the page says to see the Docs, but doesn't provide a link.

I assume you're referring to this text on the page:
[image: screenshot of docs]

Enter `Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior` into the search box at the top of the page, and you'll find the relevant docs:

[image]

Comment: Also, links to any dependencies appear on this list in the bottom left

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the **Overview** page. To see the API, click the `<paper-dialog>` text in the **Elements** section on the left side of the page:
[image]